# Determine all real x for which the following series converges $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{k}}{k!} x^{k}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine all real x for which the following series converges $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{k}}{k!} x^{k}$.
You may use the fact that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k!}{{\sqrt{2 \pi k}} (\frac{k}{e})^{k}}=1$.

My attempt:
By ratio test: $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}={x}{e}.$

It is convergent when $x <\frac{1}{e}$ and divergent when $x >\frac{1}{e}$.

At $x=\frac{1}{e}$, $a_{k}=\frac{k^{k}}{k!} \frac{1}{e^{k}}$ and choose $b_{k}=\frac{1}{k^{2}}$.

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=0$. We know that $\sum{b_{k}}$ is convergent. This implies $\sum{a_{k}}$ is also convergent.

Is my solution is correct?
Can anyone suggest me how I use the given hint to solve this question?

Comment: You are considering only positive values of $x$.

Comment: I think negative values come in $(x < \frac{1}{e})$

Comment: The answer is wrong. It is not true that thee series converges for all $x <\frac 1 e$. Absolute value is absolutely essential!

Comment: Do you mean, it is convergent when $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The series converges for $|x|<\frac1e$ and diverges for $|x|>\frac1e$.

For the case $x=\frac1e$ we can use directly the given limit

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k!}{{\sqrt{2 \pi k}} (\frac{k}{e})^{k}}=1 \implies a_{k}=\frac{k^{k}}{k!} \frac{1}{e^{k}} =\frac{{\sqrt{2 \pi k}} (\frac{k}{e})^{k}}{k!}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi k}}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi k}}$$

and therefore in this case the series diverges.

For the case $x=-\frac1e$ it converges by alternating series test.

Comment: Is there is any mistake in my solution? and thanks for the hint.

Comment: @kapil Yes, there is a mistake as I pointed out in my comment above.

Comment: @kapil Tha ratio test requires $\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|<1$ therefore the condition we obtain for the convergence is $|x|<1/e$.

Comment: Can you tell me the mistake in my solution for $x=\frac{1}{e}$ case?

Comment: @kapil By the given limit$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=\infty$.

Comment: I think $k^{k}$ will cancel with the $k!$ when we take $k$ common. Then $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k^{2}}{e^{k}}=0$ by L'Hospital. Rule. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: @kapil It suffices that you use the given limit and apply the same method I used.

Comment: @kapil You see $$\frac{a_{k}}{1/k^2}=\frac{k^{k}k^2}{k!} \frac{1}{e^{k}} =\frac{{\sqrt{2 \pi k}} (\frac{k}{e})^{k}}{k!}\cdot \frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi k}}\sim \frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi k}}\to \infty$$